# Cartoon: spaceship carrying a life-giving crystal crashes on an ocean world, shadowy evil tries to capture it

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, cartoon

This is a very old cartoon I had seen in it way before 2005 as a kid.

The point is, I think there is a guy with blond hair and his spaceship crashing onto a waterplanet to the bottom of the sea.  There are fish people and all sorts of water creatures, I think also normal humans who live in their underwater domes.

The guy's spaceship has a big crystal that has the specialty of giving life to a planet or whatever.  He takes it directly to or from his dead planet.

That's what the ominous dark lord wants to take himself by manipulating everyone in the background for some reason.  He can see everything, he knows everything, but he was that type of villain who need helpers.  I don't remember what it looked like because it either didn't have a body or just didn't show up.

If I remember correctly, the guy lost his consciousness in the fall.  They take him to the human palace and he goes on an adventure with a blonde princess.

Then the dark lord casts a shadow over their castle and convinces the princess's father, the human king, that the stranger is dangerous.  He sends his fish-people general, who, with his army of aquatic creatures, explores the seabed.

The villain then invades the fish general's mind and leads him to the crashed spaceship.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You have a pretty good question here already, but you might still be able to improve it if you go through the [suggestions for story-id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) and [suggestions for anime-id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/101407) to see if they help you remember any more details to [edit] into your question.  For example, what language was it in?

Comment: Really old...2005...oof. I feel like a geezer now.  Also maybe it's Storm Hawks?

Comment: Nope! Not the Storm Hawks :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone found it for me. *[The New Adventures of Ocean Girl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Adventures_of_Ocean_Girl)* was a 2000 cartoon reboot to the 1990s series *[Ocean Girl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean_Girl)*.

> On the planet of Oceana there were four life giving crystals guarded by the Sacred Whales, the keepers of wisdom. Thousands of years ago Galiel, the evil space wizard, stole one of the crystals and upset the balance of nature. Now Neri, Princess of Oceana, must search for the crystal and restore the balance of nature.

Galiel is weakened as the power of his crystal wanes. He's attached to a life-support system, and until late in the series, can only project himself as a shadow from the Containment Chamber.

[image]

### First Episode